# How do i this Verification widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, verification

I have this DESIGN [image: this]

how do i create this widget in flutter ?

Comment: You can checkout this library https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it without package. Result in image below.

[image]

```
class OTPScreen extends StatefulWidget { 
   final String email; 
   final String type; 
  
   const OTPScreen( 
     this.email, 
     this.type, { 
     Key? key, 
   }) : super(key: key); 
  
   @override 
   State<OTPScreen> createState() => _OTPScreenState(); 
 } 
  
 class _OTPScreenState extends State<OTPScreen> { 
   final List<FocusNode> _nodes = [ 
     FocusNode(), 
     FocusNode(), 
     FocusNode(), 
     FocusNode(), 
   ]; 
  
   final List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [ 
     TextEditingController(), 
     TextEditingController(), 
     TextEditingController(), 
     TextEditingController(), 
   ]; 
  
   final List<String> _inputs = ['7', '8', '9', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2', '3']; 
  
   final _controller = Get.put(OtpController()); 
  
   @override 
   Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
     return Scaffold( 
       body: Column( 
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
         children: [ 
           const Spacer(), 
           Text( 
             'enterotp'.tr, 
             style: const TextStyle( 
               fontSize: 32, 
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, 
               color: ColorPalette.qlessApp, 
             ), 
           ), 
           Text( 
             '${'wesentitto'.tr} ${widget.email.substring(0, 3)}*******${widget.email.substring(10)}', 
             style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey), 
           ), 
           Spaces.vertical20, 
           Row( 
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
             children: [0, 1, 2, 3] 
                 .map( 
                   (index) => Padding( 
                     padding: Paddings.p8, 
                     child: SizedBox( 
                       width: 50, 
                       child: TextField( 
                         maxLength: 1, 
                         maxLines: 1, 
                         inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[ 
                           FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly 
                         ], 
                         controller: _controllers[index], 
                         textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, 
                         keyboardType: TextInputType.none, 
                         focusNode: _nodes[index], 
                         autofocus: index == 0, 
                         decoration: const InputDecoration(counterText: ''), 
                       ), 
                     ), 
                   ), 
                 ) 
                 .toList(), 
           ), 
           //Spaces.vertical20, 
           // const Text( 
           //   'Resend code in 00:50', 
           //   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: ColorPalette.lightBlack), 
           // ), 
           Expanded( 
             flex: 5, 
             child: GridView.count( 
               reverse: true, 
               shrinkWrap: true, 
               physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), 
               childAspectRatio: 1.5, 
               crossAxisCount: 3, 
               children: [ 
                 // TextButton( 
                 //   style: TextButton.styleFrom( 
                 //       backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
                 //       primary: ColorPalette.qlessApp), 
                 //   child: const Icon(Icons.fingerprint_rounded, size: 40), 
                 //   onPressed: () async { 
                 //     await _controller.authenticate(widget.email); 
                 //   }, 
                 // ), 
                 //Disabled Biometric Authentiction 
                 TextButton( 
                   style: TextButton.styleFrom( 
                       backgroundColor: Colors.white, primary: Colors.white), 
                   onPressed: null, 
                   child: Container(), 
                 ), 
                 TextButton( 
                   style: TextButton.styleFrom( 
                       backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
                       primary: ColorPalette.qlessApp), 
                   child: const Text( 
                     '0', 
                     style: TextStyle( 
                       color: ColorPalette.lightBlack, 
                       fontSize: 28, 
                     ), 
                   ), 
                   onPressed: () => addNumber('0'), 
                 ), 
                 TextButton( 
                   style: TextButton.styleFrom( 
                       backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
                       primary: ColorPalette.qlessApp), 
                   child: const Icon(Icons.backspace_rounded, size: 35), 
                   onPressed: () => removeNumber(), 
                 ), 
                 ..._inputs.map( 
                   (i) => TextButton( 
                     style: TextButton.styleFrom( 
                         backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
                         primary: ColorPalette.qlessApp), 
                     child: Text(i, 
                         style: const TextStyle( 
                             color: ColorPalette.lightBlack, fontSize: 28)), 
                     onPressed: () => addNumber(i), 
                   ), 
                 ), 
               ], 
             ), 
           ) 
         ], 
       ), 
     ); 
   } 
  
   void addNumber(String i) { 
     if (_controllers[0].text.isEmpty) { 
       _controllers[0].text = i; 
       _nodes[1].requestFocus(); 
     } else if (_controllers[1].text.isEmpty) { 
       _controllers[1].text = i; 
       _nodes[2].requestFocus(); 
     } else if (_controllers[2].text.isEmpty) { 
       _controllers[2].text = i; 
       _nodes[3].requestFocus(); 
     } else if (_controllers[3].text.isEmpty) { 
       _controllers[3].text = i; 
     } 
  
     bool completed = true; 
     for (var cont in _controllers) { 
       if (cont.text.isEmpty) { 
         completed = false; 
         break; 
       } 
     } 
  
     if (completed) { 
       _controller.confirmOtp( 
         int.parse( 
             '${_controllers[0].text}${_controllers[1].text}${_controllers[2].text}${_controllers[3].text}'), 
         widget.email, 
         widget.type, 
       ); 
     } 
   } 
  
   void removeNumber() { 
     for (var element in _nodes) { 
       if (element.hasFocus) { 
         _controllers[_nodes.indexOf(element)].clear(); 
       } 
     } 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: if you're happy with the answer you should mark it correct and up vote it,,thanks